# AWS DMS migration causes null primary key error

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am using AWS RDS postgres database with django. I migrated the database to a new RDS postgres instance. I am able to connect to it through django and view all the records. But whenever I try to add records lets say new user it gives me

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

and sometimes I also get

```
Primary key (id) duplication error.
```

I don't understand, django is supposed to handle primary keys (id) and auto increments by default. It is strange why it is passing null while creating new records or why passing those keys which are already in use.

Here is full error traceback when i try to add a new user with post request at `http://localhost:8004/auth/registration/`

```
Error Traceback:

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, pbkdf2_sha256$24000$1cswEvhYDOKU$HHvyyKyGO66j52iXtj3AD7ugos0s7so..., null, f, first_name, First_name, Last_Name, temp@example.com, f, t, 2017-10-26 09:13:30.790302+00).
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in post
  192.         return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/views.py" in create
  38.         user = self.perform_create(serializer)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/views.py" in perform_create
  44.         user = serializer.save(self.request)

File "/home/user/savemyscope/save-my-scope-django/savemyscope/users/serializers.py" in save
  132.         adapter.save_user(request, user, self)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py" in save_user
  214.             user.save()

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in save
  74.         super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  700.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  728.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  812.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  851.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1060.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py" in execute
  159.         return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py" in _record
  101.             return method(sql, params)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/save-my-scope-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /auth/registration/
Exception Value: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, pbkdf2_sha256$24000$1cswEvhYDOKU$HHvyyKyGO66j52iXtj3AD7ugos0s7so..., null, f, first_name, First_name, Last_Name, temp@example.com, f, t, 2017-10-26 09:13:30.790302+00)
```

I am unable to figure out what is wrong in whole process. It is simple homogenous DMS migration from postgres to postgres. Migration task completes successfully. It shows no errors. All the data and tables with public schema are replicated successfully. But i am unable to add new records to it.

Note: I tried migrating db using "pg_dump" command and it worked fine. I was able to add records to it after migration. Also I tried using same postgres engine versions (9.5) on both instances.

Any type of help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Django doesn’t pass the primary key when inserting a new row. The database sets primary key automatically. If you get a duplication error, that suggests that you need to reset the sequence after migrating data across. If you get a null value error, that suggests that the table does not have a primary key. It’s hard to offer any more specific advice without seeing the old scheme, new scheme, model and full traceback of the errror.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair i added full error traceback to the question as well. Waiting for your kind response

Comment: @Alasdair i am able to successfully add new user to "users_user" table by running "INSERT INTO .. . . " command  manually while providing all values in cluding "id". I guess its django which is sending 'null' as "id" while adding new record to a table. Although it is supposed to send a the total number of records created so far plus 1 (auto increment id).

Comment: Django isn't meant to send the id when inserting a new row. It would cause race conditions when two different processes tried to insert a new row at the same time. As I said before, the problem appears to be in the tables created by dms. Check the schema of the `users_user` table in the old and new databases.

Comment: yes, schemas differ. "modifiers" value for  "id" is :
(1) Before migration 
not null default nextval('users_user_id_seq'::regclass)

(2) After migration 
not null 

It seems dms does not add "default nextval('users_user_id_seq'::regclass)" to "id" column's modifier while creating new table.

Comment: Then you'll need to find a way to make dms add the default, or add it manually. You should also set the `users_user_id_seq` to be above the max id in the table, otherwise you'll get the duplicate errors.

Comment: oh and also relation "users_user_id_seq" does not exist after migration. I guess dms did not copy this relation for any table and hence it could not set default = table_name_seq_id for "id" column.

Comment: also users_user_id_seq is not listed when i try \dt or even try viewing tables with public schema.. and dms migrates those relations with schema type = public. any suggestions how to view to migrate id_seq relations as i can specify rules to target tables with specific schema type while defining dms migration task

Comment: I haven't used DMS, so I can't help with how to migrate the sequences.

Comment: okay @Alasdair. Well thanks alot. it was very helpful. Yes it solves the issue once i have the seq_id table for every relation in the db and set the default value for id column. Thanks so much.